# golang чтение сообщений из телеграм канала

Tags: api, golang, telegram

Мне нужно как-то читать сообщения из телеграм канала с помощью go (обязательно). Перепробовал достаточно много способов, дальше всего зашел с `github.com/gotd/td/telegram`,  всю апишку перебрал, но все равно не получается.

Помогите с поиском решения.

Добавляю лучшее из того, что уже есть. Код ниже написан с помощью примера из выше указанного репозитория. Он пишет в логи список каналов на которые подписан пользователь и их id.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gotd/td/examples"
    "github.com/gotd/td/telegram"
    "github.com/gotd/td/telegram/auth"
    "github.com/gotd/td/tg"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

// noSignUp can be embedded to prevent signing up.
type noSignUp struct{}

func (c noSignUp) SignUp(ctx context.Context) (auth.UserInfo, error) {
    return auth.UserInfo{}, errors.New("not implemented")
}

func (c noSignUp) AcceptTermsOfService(ctx context.Context, tos tg.HelpTermsOfService) error {
    return &auth.SignUpRequired{TermsOfService: tos}
}

// termAuth implements authentication via terminal.
type termAuth struct {
    noSignUp

    phone string
}

func (a termAuth) Phone(_ context.Context) (string, error) {
    return a.phone, nil
}

func (a termAuth) Password(_ context.Context) (string, error) {
    fmt.Print("Enter 2FA password: ")
    bytePwd, err := terminal.ReadPassword(0)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return strings.TrimSpace(string(bytePwd)), nil
}

func (a termAuth) Code(_ context.Context, _ *tg.AuthSentCode) (string, error) {
    fmt.Print("Enter code: ")
    code, err := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return strings.TrimSpace(code), nil
}

func main() {
    const (
        phone   = "phone_number"
        appID   = app_id //int
        apiHash = "api_hash"
    )

    examples.Run(func(ctx context.Context, logger *zap.Logger) error {
        // Setting up authentication flow helper based on terminal auth.
        flow := auth.NewFlow(
            termAuth{phone: phone},
            auth.SendCodeOptions{},
        )

        client := telegram.NewClient(appID, apiHash, telegram.Options{})
        return client.Run(ctx, func(ctx context.Context) error {
            if err := client.Auth().IfNecessary(ctx, flow); err != nil {
                return err
            }

            logger.Info("Success")

            chats, err := client.API().MessagesGetAllChats(ctx, []int64{})
            if err != nil {
                logger.Error("get all chats")
                return err
            }
            for _, chat := range chats.GetChats() {
                fc, ok := chat.AsFull()
                if !ok {
                    logger.Error("chat as full", zap.String("chat", chat.String()))
                    continue
                }
                logger.Info("show chat", zap.Int64("id", fc.GetID()), zap.String("name", fc.GetTitle()))
            }

            return nil
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: а сможете показать ваши наработки хоть какие-то?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, обновил содержание вопроса.

Comment: спасибо. а можете еще сказать в какой строке что не получается? ошибки может быть выдает? пустой список? опишите ожидаемый результат и фактический

Comment: @SeniorPomidor мне нужно получать сообщения из канала. Проблема в том, что я не знаю даже какой метод API мне для этого использовать. Там есть метод ChannelsGetMessages, но он принимает в себя контекст и структуру, в которой нужно указать channelID и список ID сообщений, которые я хочу забрать. Но вот откуда мне взять список ID сообщений, если у меня их нет? Очень странное API. Вообщем, проблема не в ошибках, а в том, что не ясно, что использовать, и как, для решения поставленной задачи.